Vulnerable child dependencies fix required, nextjs, nodejs
I am doing npm audit on my project and I am getting
# npm audit report
d3-color  <3.1.0
Severity: high
d3-color vulnerable to ReDoS - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-36jr-mh4h-2g58
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-simple-maps@1.0.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/d3-transition/node_modules/d3-color
node_modules/react-simple-maps/node_modules/d3-color
  d3-interpolate  0.1.3 - 2.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of d3-color
  node_modules/d3-transition/node_modules/d3-interpolate
  node_modules/react-simple-maps/node_modules/d3-interpolate
    d3-transition  0.0.7 - 2.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of d3-color
    Depends on vulnerable versions of d3-interpolate
    node_modules/d3-transition
    d3-zoom  0.0.2 - 2.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of d3-interpolate
    Depends on vulnerable versions of d3-transition
    node_modules/react-simple-maps/node_modules/d3-zoom
      react-simple-maps  2.0.0 - 3.0.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of d3-zoom
      node_modules/react-simple-maps

I tried various things like using overrides, installing these child dependencies directly, but while running the application I get wierd ES module errors
Uncaught Error: require() of ES Module

I am not being able to figure out how to fix this and it seems like all these child dependencies are interlinked.
Please advise. Also please don't suggest to run npm audit fix --force, that is not I want.

It's unclear how you caused this error and so it's unknown how to fix it. "audit" always needs sanity check instead of trying blindly to fix it. There may be no vulnerability to fix if it's impossible for a culprit to affect vulnerable dependency in a way it can cause problems. This needs to be checked, but I'd assume this is the case here. Does your app allows a user to input custom color for a map and save it on a server without validation, so it could affect other users through d3-color vulnerability? No? Then there is no possibility

Also these problems are always discussed in issues, e.g. https://github.com/zcreativelabs/react-simple-maps/issues/349 . It's unknown if you followed this to fix it or something else

No my app doesn't have any options to input custom color for a map or alter it. These packages are all internally being used by react-simple-maps and re-chart packages. I haven't installed these packages manually. Now, when I am doing a npm audit I am receiving these 5 high severity vulnerabilities that I want to remove.

You don't need to do anything in this case, unless you want to create extra work for yourself. As I said, audit reports need sanity checks. If they bother you for some reason, there are third-party packages that allow to ignore false positives in audit

Thanks for clearing the doubts. I will ignore them as they are not disturbing the app
